# extract-text-webpack-plugin - How to create hash name (unique name only if file change)

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, extract-text-plugin

I have the following question, I'm using: 
extract-text-webpack-plugin version 2.0.0-rc.2 in webpack 2, and I noticed that even that I change only JS files the name of the css file is changed.

I have in my webpack config the following:

`new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].[hash].css")`

I want to use long cache for my CSS file, meaning that only when the file CSS is changed the hash should be different.

How I can do this, for my JS files is working just fine

BTW - This is the same behaviour in webpack 1

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can create a css file with a content hash by using the following in your webpack.config.js plugins:

```
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles-[contenthash].css'),
  ]
```

Sample full webpack config:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack'); 
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.[chunkhash].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: 'css-loader'
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: './src/index.html'}),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.[contenthash].css'),
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the [docs for `ExtractTextPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/extract-text-webpack-plugin/#options) and find that `filename` supports the following placeholders: `[name]`, `[id]` and `[contenthash]` (hash of the content of the extracted file).